# Google Chrome Extension: Create tabs and populate textarea with text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to open up a set of tabs based on some URLs that I have and then input text into textareas on these tabs based on some concomitant data that goes with the URL. Here's what I've got:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#sendinput").click(function() {
        var data = readInputLines($("#input"));
        data.map(function(item) {
            chrome.tabs.create({active:true, url:item["page_url"]}, fillText);
        });
    });
});

function readInputLines(textarea) {
    var data = textarea.val().split("\n").map(function(item) {
        return item.split("\t");
    });
    var data_dict = data.slice(1,data.length).map(function(item) {
        var dict = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            dict[data[0][i]] = item[i];
        }
        return dict; 
    });
    return data_dict;
}

function fillText(tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabUpdatedId, changeInfo, tabUpdated){
        if (tabUpdatedId == tab.id && changeInfo.status && changeInfo.status == 'complete'){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabUpdatedId, {code: 'document.getElementById("comment_body").value = "TESTING TESTING"'});
        }
    });
}
```

And this doesn't seem to do anything in terms of putting "TESTING TESTING" in this textarea on the pages/tabs that I'm opening. I'm having trouble using console.log with the chrome extension so it's hard to tell what's going on.

What is the correct way to do this?

To summarize, the idea is that I have a list of dictionaries with URLs and templates of text. From there, I want to go through that list and open each url in a new tab and then when the tab is loaded, fill in the template text into the text area. Surely this shouldn't be too difficult (famous last words?)

Thanks!

Comment: You should read the overview: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview

Comment: Please provide complete code, including your `manifest.json`, it would help a lot for debugging